# Quoting values with JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have an object I'm creating that looks like this:

```
let outputOut = {
    "_id": id[i],
    "regNum": code[i],
    "sd": sd[i],
    "pd": ptOut,
    "p": p[i],
...}
//output 
fs.writeFile('./output/file.json', JSON.stringify(output, null, 2), 'utf-8');
```

However, I need the "p" values in this object to be wrapped in quotation marks. As-is it just prints out the values without quotation marks.

I tried escaping the quote characters, via:

```
"p": "\"" + p[i] + "\"'",
```

Which turns out like [this](http://pastebin.com/KeLSXNgC), I also tried doing this:

```
"p": '"' + p[i] + '"',
```

Which outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/7GWaqG1L).

How can I get the *p* values to be wrapped in quotations marks, i.e: "139500000"  ?

Comment: If the value is a string, it will be output with quotation marks. Is that what you want? If so, all you need is a quick preprocessing step to convert the value of the `p` property to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the "p" values in this object to be wrapped in quotation marks.

In other words you, want these values to be **strings**. Strings in JSON are represented as `"..."`. It seems like `p[i]` is a number. You can explicitly convert a value to a string by calling `String(x)` or `x.toString()`:

```
"p": String(p[i]),
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I should of realized this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A string-valued property will be stringified as a string, that is, with quotation marks.

```
let outputOut = {
    "_id": id[i],
    "regNum": code[i],
    "sd": sd[i],
    "pd": ptOut,
    "p": String(p[i]),
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
...}
```

Another idea is to use the `replacer` parameter to `JSON.stringify`:

```
JSON.stringify(output, function(key, value) {
  if (key === 'p') value = String(value);
  return value;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me.

```
var value = 1023;

var p = '\"'+ value + '\"';
console.log(p);
```

You can check the fiddle i have created.

https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/1dkhjpjw/

Comment: Um, what is the purpose of the back-slashes?

Comment: That will create a string that literally contains quotation marks. The JSON will look like `"p": "\"123\""` which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, I tried this solution. But the backslashes appear in the JSON, and I cannot get them to go away